# Show progress while sleep in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a simple script which must show progress while user waiting. But I get infinitive loop and seems sleep not working. What wrong in this code?

```
#!/bin/bash

spinner=(
"Working    "
"Working.   "
"Working..  "
"Working... "
"Working...."
)

while sleep 10 
  do
    for item in ${spinner[*]}
      do
        echo -en "\r$item"
        sleep .1
        echo -en "\r              \r"
      done
  done
```

Comment: `sleep 10` will always return non-error so `while sleep 10` is logically equivalent to `while true`.

Comment: wow, didn't know that.. So how can I show progress while user wait? Anyway I need use sleep, right?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to sleep for 10 seconds and print a message every second, you can try a for-loop, or a while with another variable serving as a flag

Comment: `sleep 10` will wait for 10 seconds before continuing, so the progress will not show up until the 10 seconds have already passed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea:

- using the `bash` (system) variable [SECONDS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-SECONDS) to measure our 10 seconds
- using a `tput` code for ovewriting a line
- eliminating the `spinner[]` array (since the only difference in values is the number of trailing periods)

---

```
EraseToEOL=$(tput el)
max=$((SECONDS + 10))              # add 10 seconds to current count

while [ $SECONDS -le ${max} ]
do
    msg='Waiting'
    for i in {1..5}
    do
        printf "%s" "${msg}"
        msg='.'
        sleep .1
    done
    printf "\r${EraseToEOL}"
done
printf "\n"
```

---

A small change to OP's current code using the `max/SECONDS` approach:

```
spinner=(
"Working    "
"Working.   "
"Working..  "
"Working... "
"Working...."
)

max=$((SECONDS + 10))

while [[ ${SECONDS} -le ${max} ]]
do
    for item in ${spinner[*]}
    do
        echo -en "\r$item"
        sleep .1
        echo -en "\r              \r"
    done
done
```

Comment: Also nice is `spinner=( '|' '/' '-' '\' );`

Answer (score 3):

My method of showing progress while sleeping in bash:

```
sleep 5 | pv -t
```

It probably can't get any simpler than that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the in/decrement variable `i` to put out the array...

```
#!/bin/bash

countdown(){
spinner=(
"Working    "
"Working.   "
"Working..  "
"Working... "
"Working...."
)

i=4

if [ ${i} -lt 5 ]
then
 while true
  do
   for i in ${i}
    do
     printf "%s    \t" ${spinner[i]}
     sleep .1
     printf "\r"
     sleep .1
     if [ ${i} -eq 0 ]
      then
       # Here you can clean up or do what to do at zero count
       printf "\n"
       unset i
       unset spinner
       return 0 # Can be used in ${?} from parent bash
     else
      i=$((${i}-1))
    fi
  done
 done
return 1 # Should never be executed
fi
}

# A funny cd ;-)
cd(){
countdown && printf "%s\n" "DONE changing to "${1} # Gives out if return is 0 (${?})
unset cd
cd ${1}
}
#
cd ~
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out this [spiner](https://github.com/vaniacer/spiner)

[image]

Or from this [project](https://github.com/vaniacer/kube-dialog)

[image]